# momentjs days difference between two GMT dates

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm trying to get difference of days between two GMT dates using moment

but I couldn't find it.

I'm on IST(+05:30) and I have some GMT dates(-05:00) in db,

I tried using following command

`temp2.diff(temp1, "days")`

here is a screenshot of all the commands tried in console
[image]

there we can clears see that dates are different and still shows the difference is 0

here is how I'm initializing moment objects of `'America/New_York'`

```
var temp1 = moment.tz(new Date('Mon Jan 25 2016 22:00:00 GMT-0600'), 'America/New_York');
 var temp2 = moment.tz(new Date('Tue Jan 26 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0600'), 'America/New_York');
```

any help appreaciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, there is less than 24 hours difference between those dates, so it's correct. The [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) says:

> By default, `moment#diff` will return number rounded down. If you want the floating point number, pass true as the third argument.

```
> temp2.diff(temp1, "days", true)
0.08333333333333333
```

---

If you don't care about the hours at all, set them to `0` before you do the comparison

```
> temp2.hours(0).diff(temp1.hours(0), "days")
1
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get the difference bettween dates then? here as the dates are different I wan the output to be 1

Comment: I just tried this, math round is giving me `0` so I use `Math.ceil` but If I use like that, if I have two dates with same day and different hours then also it is returning 1. My requirement is just want to know two dates are same or not, If not what is the difference in days between those two dates

Comment: If you don't care about the hours at all, set them to `0` before you do the comparison. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

A few things:

1. You say that you are retrieving these values from a database, but then you show us loading them via the `Date` constructor from a string value.  If you are really storing a string in your database, especially in that particular format, then you have much larger problems than the one you asked about!  Please show us *precisely* how you load the values from your database to begin with.
2. You shouldn't rely on the `Date` object for parsing, especially when you are already using moment, which has much better parsing routines of its own.
3. You said these values where in `America/New_York`, but then you show an offset of `-0600`.  That's never used in that time zone.  The offset for the value you showed would be `-0500`.
4. You also said "I have some GMT dates(-05:00)" - which doesn't make any sense.  GMT is +00:00.  GMT-0500 means "5 hours *behind* GMT".  Thus, you no longer have a "GMT date".
5. Be aware that the JavaScript `Date` object can *only* use the time zone of where the code is running.  You cannot run it in any other time zone.
6. While Felix is correct in how you can show decimals with the `diff` function, you should realize that `diff` is giving you the actual elapsed time between the two moments in time you asked about.  However, you seem to be wanting to know the total number of calendar days separating the two days that the moments fall into within the named time zone.  To do that, you'd need to ignore the time portion.  Using `startOf('day')` is an easy way to do that.  Consider:

   ```
   var a = moment.parseZone("2016-01-25T23:00:00-05:00");
   var b = moment.parseZone("2016-01-26T01:00:00-05:00");

   b.diff(a, 'days', true) // 0.08333333333333333  (not what you want)

   b.startOf('day').diff(a.startOf('day'), 'days') // 1   (that's better!)

   moment(b).startOf('day').diff(moment(a).startOf('day'),'days')  // 1  (best approach)
   ```

   Note a few things with this code:

   - The code in the last line is the best approach, as it leaves the original values of `a` and `b` alone.  Otherwise, they would be modified.  (Moments are mutable.)
   - You seem to already have the correct local time and offset, and thus there's no need to use moment-timezone's `tz` function.  You can just use `parseZone`.  Of course if this was just a side effect of your example, then you could still use moment-timezone, but I'd strongly recommend against using the `Date` constructor still.

Comment: I'm saving in the following format in db `"start" : "Wed Jan 27 2016 23:00:00 GMT-0500",`, are there going to be any  issues with that? If I use that string directly like `moment(string)` there is a warning saying `momentjs falls back to js date`, that is why I'm creating `Date` object then parsing using `moment`

Comment: Moment was trying to warn you that using that string would fall back to the Date object for parsing.  You've effectively eliminated the warning - not the problem it was trying to warn you about!  What database are you using? There's always a native type that is a better option than a string.